How to clear Nvidia GPU RAM after OOM in Optuna study using DDP
I have 4 GPUs on my server and Im using Torch DDP to distribute the training across my GPUs.  I want my Optuna trial to gracefully fail and move on to the next trial without crashing the study when the trial causes CUDA OOM.
I execute this function when my objective function hits an exception:
    gc.collect()
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    torch.cuda.synchronize()

    if torch.distributed.is_initialized():
        torch.distributed.destroy_process_group()
        while torch.distributed.is_initialized():
            time.sleep(1)

    process_info = os.popen("nvidia-smi | grep 'python' | awk '{print $5}'").read().splitlines()

    for pid in process_info:
        try:
            pid = int(pid.strip())
            print(f"Killing process with PID: {pid}")
            os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to kill process {pid}: {e}")

    time.sleep(5)

...but it works too well and it kills the Optuna study process itself.  How can I just release the GPU RAM without killing the processes that my Optuna study/DDP process rely on to keep the study alive?
